# How can I handle conditional comments in a ractive mustache template?

Tags: express, mustache, ractivejs

I am having and issue using express and ractive to render mustache templates.  My actual code looks something like this:

```
<li class="header-link"><a href="fakehome.com">HOME</a></li>
<li class="header-link">
  <!--[if !IE]><a href="{{url('browse')}}">BROWSE</a><![endif]-->
  <!--[if IE]><a href="{{url('ie_browse')}}">BROWSE</a><![endif]-->
</li>
```

But when the page renders it does not include the conditional [if IE] blocks.  I think it may be interpreting them as comments.  Anyways I need a way to modify which links I use for compatibility with IE.   If there is another way to do this I would happily accept it, but I was somewhat surprised this did not render at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fake it with triple mustaches:

```
<li class="header-link">
  {{{ifnotie}}}<a href="{{url('browse')}}">BROWSE</a>{{{ifend}}}
  {{{ifie}}}<a href="{{url('ie_browse')}}">BROWSE</a>{{{ifend}}}
</li>
```

and constants in your data:

```
data: {
    ifie: '<!--[if IE]>',
    ifnotie: '<!--[if !IE]>', 
    ifend: '<![endif]-->',
    url: function(input) { return input }
}
```

and:

```
console.log(ractive.toHTML())
//yields:
<li class="header-link"><!--[if !IE]><a href="browse">BROWSE</a><![endif]--> <!--[if IE]><a href="ie_browse">BROWSE</a><![endif]--></li>
```

Comment: This is actually quite cool! Wouldn't work in browser, but it seems as a good solution for back-end.